# Getting "Timed out waiting for script to complete" in selenium Java whereas I have not used any asynchronous code in script

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using selenium grid with docker and running 6 parallel tests on windows node with IE , its working well but rarely I am getting below error and I have used implicit wait for 120 seconds at the start of login function(so it will be applicable to all code until drivers life)

Script is showing "Test request status is 'submitted',success"(expected) and then its waiting for 120 seconds before click on reset button and then below error is getting (alert pop up should come after click on reset)

code:

1.

```
       if (status.equals("Submitted")) {
            
            appUtils.setPassDescription(node, "Test request status is 'submitted',success");
            logger.info("Test request status is 'submitted',success");

        } else if (status.equals("Not Submitted")) {
            appUtils.setFailDescription(node, "Test request status is 'Not submitted',failure");
            logger.error("Test request status is 'Not submitted',failure");
        }

        cnf.alertHandle("ok",node);
```

2. 

```
public void alertHandle(String type, ExtentTest node) {
        try {

            clickElement(sUtils.getElementByCSSSelector(loginElms.resetTestButtonCss), 10, "Reset", node);

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            Alert alertOK = driver.get().switchTo().alert();

            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){
                alertOK.accept();
                appUtils.setTestStepsInfo(node,"Clicked on 'Ok' of Reset");
            }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("cancel"))
            {
                alertOK.dismiss();
                appUtils.setTestStepsInfo(node,"Clicked on 'Cancel' of Reset");
            }

            Thread.sleep(3000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            appUtils.setFailDescription(node, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
Timed out waiting for script to complete.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11- 
14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'bld02600012', ip: '10.54.228.104', os.name: 'Linux', 
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: 
'1.8.0_261'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, 
browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, 
platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: 
{browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: 
true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, 
ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, 
ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, 
initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:52445/, nativeEvents: true, 
requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, 
pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, webdriver.remote.sessionid: cc942e9f-96f3- 
4a63-8337-5ba...}
Session ID: cc942e9f-96f3-4a63-8337-5ba5eb4f506c
```

I am surprised as I have not used any javascript code, as per my understanding we will get this error if we are handling any async call (please correct me if I am wrong), can someone please tell me why I am gettign this error

- selenium - 3.141.59
- testng - 6.14.3
- maven - 3.6.0
- IEDriver - 3.14.0
- Java  - 1.8.0_261

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Timed out waiting for script to complete. 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' 
System info: host: 'bld02600012', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
```

...implies that the *IEDriverServer* was unable to interact with the new *Browsing Context* i.e. *InternetExplorer Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *java.version* is **1.8.0_112** which is quite **old** and **ancient**.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u252](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Hi,I tried the version of JDK which you mentioned above.But I am still getting same error above.My Concern is I Should get specific error to specific action which describes what the issue is. But in my case if I am getting error anywhere like above example - suppose its unable to select any drop down value, In this case also getting the same error above

Comment: I have updated my question with updated java version 1.8.0_261